# Lambda inside if statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

How can I use lambda inside an if statement to compare a treenode's value to an object value inside a list ? Currently I am trying something like this but it won't work. Is there any better way to simplify my search?

```
if (tvItems.Nodes.Count > 0)
{
    // Get checked items
    listChecked= MenuItemDTOManager.GetMenuItems();
    //

    foreach (TreeNode parentNode in tvItems.Nodes)
    {
        if (listChecked.Find(s => s.menuId.ToString() == parentNode.Value.ToString()))
        {
            parentNode.Checked = true;
        }
    }
    // Traverse children
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can since you are already showing a lambda inside an if statement. But what is it that you are trying to do? And what doesn't work?

Comment: That was not working since if returns bool & Find does not. However I have found the answer thanks to @Cuong Le

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be using [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) instead of `Find`:

```
if (listChecked.Any(s => s.menuId.ToString() == parentNode.Value.ToString()))
{
    parentNode.Checked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`if` requires a `bool` value only.

```
listChecked.Find(s => s.menuId.ToString() == parentNode.Value.ToString())
```

[Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx) won't return `bool`.

Try using [Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca.aspx) instead of `Find`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for the following.

```
foreach (TreeNode parentNode in tvItems.Nodes.OfType<TreeNode>().Any(n=> listChecked.Any(s => s.menuId.ToString() == n.Value.ToString()))
{
    parentNode.Checked = true;
}
```